# curious why <div title=***> becomes oldtitle after I use jQuery .css

Tags: jquery, html, title, qtip

My working code:

```
$("#selectResult").append("<div id='"+arr[this.id]+"' class='inline' 
title='Co. "+arr[this.id]+"'></div>");

$("#"+arr[this.id]).css({'background-image' : 'url(./img/coatofarms/'
+arr[this.id]+'.png)','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-position': 
'bottom'}).qtip(countyCrest);
```

In the first select where I append the div I give the title and when I inspect the element the `title` is as it should be. 
Then when I change the .css in the second select for the div, on inspect element title is now `oldtitle="Co. Down" title=""`

What is going on here?

This is the inspect element code

```
<div id="Antrim" class="inline" style="background-image: 
url(http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/09101916/trazoo/demo_1/img/coatofarms/Antrim.png);
 background-position: 50% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; " 
oldtitle="Co. Antrim" title=""></div>
```

Comment: I have a feeling this will be caused by whatever the call to `qtip` does, and not have anything to do with the call to `css`.

Comment: You may have a plugin modifying your attributes (qtip maybe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qTip empties the title attribute so that you don't see the qTip balloon and the default browser tooltip at the same time. The original title is stored in the `oldtitle` attribute.

More specifically:

> Unfortunately the title attribute has to be removed so that the default browser tooltip is supressed. Even for those elements not grabbing content from the title attribute itself, it needs to be removed, or in the case of qTip, renamed, so that we don't get two tooltips showing up!

(From https://github.com/Craga89/qTip2/issues/215)

Comment: how do we bypass it if we need it to have a tooltip in addition to the qtip tip

Comment: qTip has an core option 'suppress' enabled by default, you can set it to false and this should keep the original title attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably find that the title is being re-allocated to a new attribute by the qtip plugin rather than change to css.

Not suer about qtip, but it soudns like a tooltip plugin, so the author probably wants to stop the default browser implementation of tooltips for titles when qtip is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sth like this to your javascript:

```
$('[title!=""]').qtip({
  suppress: false
});
```

At least I got my similar problem fixed with this.
[qTip](https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2) seems to have `suppress` set to `true` [by default](https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/blob/master/src/core/defaults.js#L18) and it [replaces](https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/blob/master/src/core/jquery_methods.js#L74) the title attribute with `oldtitle`.